# Old Excel Data - Merge With SQL Transaction Log

Tags: sql, excel

So I have two years of total data from 2013 and 2014 from excel sheets. They're summed up and put onto my server. For 2015 we have a log with dates and each individual transaction. This makes it convenient to just add it all up for 2015. I want to merge the two: sum up the 2015s and then add that as its own column for the master sheet.

What I have now:

```
Company | 2013 | 2014 |
----------------------
Apple   | 300  | 200  |
Toyota  | 250  | 250  |
```

2015:

```
 Date    | Company | Units 
 -------------------------
 1/1/15  | Apple   | 30
 2/28/15 | Toyota  | 14
 3/14/15 | Toyota  | 22
```

Ideal Look:

```
Company | 2013 | 2014 | 2015
-----------------------------
Apple   | 300  | 200  | 300
Toyota  | 250  | 250  | 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your DBMS, I'm taking a shot in the dark, but I think you can handle this all directly within SQL:

```
with data_2015 as (
  select company, sum (units) as units
  from table_2015_data
  group by company
)
select
  h.Company, h.Units_2013, h.Units_2014, d.units as Units_2015
from
  history h
  left join data_2015 d on
    h.Company = d.Company
```

From there, just bring it into Excel using MSQuery.